# java - verify input validity using assert-like methods

Tags: java, validation, assert

I have a tokenizer, and I need to extract each token, and write it to an output file. The tokens must exist in some logical order (according to a language grammar). Thus, I must also validate that the tokens order follows the grammar specification.
Currently, I'm doing that by using assert-like methods that throw exceptions with appropriate messages.
Here is the code:

```
public void compileVarDec() throws IOException, IllegalSyntaxException {

    output.write("<varDec>\n");

    verifyStaticField();
    output.write("<keyword> " + tokenizer.keyWord() + " </keyword>\n");
    tokenizer.advance();

    verifyLegalType();
    output.write("<keyword> " + tokenizer.keyWord() + " </keyword>\n");
    tokenizer.advance();

    verifyIdentifier();
    output.write("<identifier> " + tokenizer.identifier() + " </identifier>\n");
    tokenizer.advance();

    verifySymbol(JackTokenizer.SEMI_COLON);
    output.write("<symbol> " + tokenizer.symbol() + " </symbol>\n");
    tokenizer.advance();

    output.write("</varDec>\n");
}

private void verifySymbol(char token) throws IllegalSyntaxException {
    if (tokenizer.tokenType() != JackTokenizer.TOKEN_TYPE.SYMBOL ||
            tokenizer.symbol() != token)
        throw new IllegalSyntaxException("Expected the symbol '" + token + "'");
}

private void verifyStaticField() throws IllegalSyntaxException {
    if (tokenizer.tokenType() != JackTokenizer.TOKEN_TYPE.KEYWORD ||
            (!tokenizer.keyWord().equals(JackTokenizer.FIELD) &&
                    !tokenizer.keyWord().equals(JackTokenizer.STATIC))) {
        throw new IllegalSyntaxException("Expected 'static' or 'field'");
    }
}

private void verifyLegalType() throws IllegalSyntaxException {
    if (tokenizer.tokenType() != JackTokenizer.TOKEN_TYPE.KEYWORD ||
            (!tokenizer.keyWord().equals(JackTokenizer.INT) &&
                    !tokenizer.keyWord().equals(JackTokenizer.CHAR) &&
                    !tokenizer.keyWord().equals(JackTokenizer.BOOLEAN)))
        throw new IllegalSyntaxException("Expected a legal type");
}

private void verifyIdentifier() throws IllegalSyntaxException {
    if (tokenizer.tokenType() != JackTokenizer.TOKEN_TYPE.IDENTIFIER)
        throw new IllegalSyntaxException("Expected an identifier");
}
```

Is it considered good practice to validate input that way? To call a method that would check the input, then, if it's invalid, will throw an exception, and the current method will just ignore the thrown exception and pass it on?
If you have other suggestions I'll be glad to hear. Note, I want to avoid running over the tokens twice, so I have to validate the input and write the output simultaneously

Comment: It's fine, but be aware that the exception stack traces will show that they were thrown in the verify methods, rather than the method that really matters.

Comment: An alternative, perhaps more common, practice is to have the called method do all the validation and delegate the real processing to a private method.

Comment: Thank you. Thing is, I don't want to do two passes on the tokens, so I have to validate and write the output simultaneously. I'll add this to the question